# What is wrong in this code? displays white color background instead of image

Tags: html, css

I using bootstrap. And my css here. It displays only white background inside of this image.

[image: Image i am using here is]

```
.container-header
    {
        max-width:1000px;
        background:url(../images/header-secondrow-new.png);
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-size: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are expecting... Do you want your image to repeat both horizontally and vertycally? Do you have any content in your `container-header` or just the image? How tall do you want this container to be?

Comment: Thanks for response.... I fixed it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
background-image: url(../images/header-secondrow-new.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: center top;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is No height value in your css code is you dnt give height value and dont add any content in that element you cant see anything. Try adding `height:100px` to css class.